# How to read a file from Firebase storage and display contents on React component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-storage

I have a file in firebase storage, how can I have my app read contents from it and then print those contents out inside my class component div? Right now I have it so that it just opens up the firebase file in a new tab.

```
class ScanResult extends Component {
    state = {
        isFinishedScanning: false
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        const storageRef = app.storage().ref();
        app.database().ref("imgScanStatus").on("value", snapshot => {
            snapshot.forEach(snap => {
                this.setState({ isFinishedScanning: snap.val() });
            });
            if (this.state.isFinishedScanning) {
                storageRef.child('scanFiles/scan.txt').getDownloadURL().then(function (url) {
                    window.open(url);//OPENS FIREBASE FILE IN NEW TAB
                });
            }
        });
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <InnerTitleBar title="Scan Result" />
                <p>Processing image...</p>
                <img src={loading} />
                <div>DATA FROM SCAN.TXT</div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files#download_data_via_url) shows how to do this.
`getDownloadURL` provides you with a URL that you must query in order to get the content of the file, then you can put this content into your component's state in order to display it.